# Symbol used for device not found error in Orcad Capture

Tags: orcad, schematic

I have made a schematic and downloaded the footprints and symbols from UltraLibrarian. When I click on a symbol on my schematic, I can see that the footprint is attached to it. But when I create a netlist, I get a lot of warnings. For example, for one such component,I get an error saying "`Symbol 'DCK0005A_N' used by RefDes U8 for device 'SN74LV1T34DCKR_DCK0005A_N_SN74L' not found`". In the folder which I downloaded off UltraLibraian, I can see that it has both the library file (OLB) file as well as the footprint(STEP file). Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: The footprint is not a STEP file. The footprint has PSM extension. The STEP file is a 3D model that can referenced from the footprint.

Comment: @PeterKarlsen  - Thanks. I have a DRA file attached when I downloaded off UltraLibrarian. How do I get a PSM file?

Comment: Have you added the folder where the foot print is into OrCad PCB? If not, then that's probably your issue.

Comment: @user3147192 - The DRA file is the footprint you make in PCB editor. When you save the DRA file, PCB Editor automaticly also creates the PSM file. It's not that logical, and I have no idea why it works that way.